# Nginx - Redirect 404 PHP files

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm using Laravel's `valet` on my local. I did not have a problem with this on my local. My remote server uses `Ubuntu 16.04`.

I have an `index.php` like so in my website's root:

```
<?php

require __dir__ . '/src/core/bootstrap.php';
require __dir__ . '/src/controllers/index.php';
```

`src/core/bootstrap.php` is stuff for `composer` and `databases`. But this is what `src/controllers/index.php` is:

```
<?php
session_start();

use App\UserTools\User;
use App\Core\Router;

$page = Router::load()->fetchPage();

include "src/controllers/{$page}.controller.php";
include "src/views/{$page}.view.php";
```

So, when users visit `site.com`, it goes to `main` since it's the home page. But, let's say, for example, they visit: `site.com/about`, then `$page` would be `about` and viola... routing. This was all taught to me on Laracasts, so excuse me if this seems... rudimentary.

The problem lies, when I visit `site.com/api`, it just shows me a blank page. Or, like, `book?id=1` blank page. Or

Here is the `nginx` block from `valet` which tells the server what to do with files not found:

```
location / {
    rewrite VALET_SERVER_PATH last;
}
```

How can I apply that to my site? I tried substituting `VALET_SERVER_PATH` with `/var/www/html` but I just got a Server Error 500.

Here is my current `nginx` block:

```
server {
    server_name www.site.org;
    return 301 $scheme://site.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name site.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-site.org.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name site.org;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

It works. But only for the front page. Yes, I have HTTPS enabled and `www` traffic gets re-directed to `non-www` URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes on the following directives:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
}
```

Comment: well, how about that. I see what's going on -- that worked! Thank you.